# Parse unstructured weblogs into structured format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have file which contains the records like,

**Input (Raw Log Record):**

> 50.57.190.149 - - [22/Apr/2012:07:12:41 +0530] "GET /computers/laptops.html?brand=819 HTTP/1.0" 200 12530 "-" "-"

**Output (Processed Log Record):**

> 50.57.190.149 - - 22/Apr/2012:07:12:41 +0530 GET /computers/laptops.html?brand=819 HTTP/1.0 computers - - laptops.html
>   brand=819 200 12530 - -

**Format of Input Data :**

1. remote-IP
2. remote-log-name
3. user
4. time
5. request-string
6. status-code
7. byte-string
8. user-agent
9. referral

**here is my code:**

```
object unStructuredToStructured {

  def main(args : Array[String]){ 

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("unStructuredToStructured").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
 import spark.implicits._

 val rdd1 = spark.read.textFile("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Downloads\\Veeresh_study\\DataSet_from_OldSessions\\weblogs\\weblogs_1_rec.txt").rdd

 val schemaString = "remote_IP remote_log_name user time request_string status_code byte_string user_agent referral"

 val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
   .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))

 val schema = StructType(fields)


 val rowRDD = rdd1.map(x => x.split(" "))
   .map(attributes => Row(attributes(0), attributes(1), attributes(2), attributes(3), attributes(4), attributes(5), attributes(6), attributes(7), attributes(8)))

 val data = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
 data.show()

}
}
```

**OutPut:**

Here is the output that I'm getting
[image: Here is the output that I'm getting]

As you could see from the image,

we are using **space** as delemeter and the Value of one field is split into multiple columns (because the field-value contains **space** in it)

ex: Ideally the "**time**" column should have the value "**[22/Apr/2012:07:12:41 +0530]**" but here its getting split into two columns i.e  "**time**" and "**request_string**"

similarly the value of **request_string** ("GET /computers/laptops.html?brand=819 HTTP/1.0") is split into "**status_code**", "**byte_string**" and **"user_agent**"

please help in parsing the field values by ignoring the space within the field-value

Comment: @Shankar How did u add the image here and is there way to get the notification of new question posted for specific tags like **Spark**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after multiple trials, definetly the below solution can be improved.

```
object unStructuredToStructured {
  def main(args : Array[String]){

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("unStructuredToStructured").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
   import spark.implicits._

   val rdd1 = spark.read.textFile("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Downloads\\Veeresh_study\\DataSet_from_OldSessions\\weblogs\\weblogs_10_lakh_rec.txt").rdd

    val schemaString = "remote_IP remote_log_name user time request_string status_code byte_string user_agent referral"

    val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
    .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))

    val schema = StructType(fields)


    val rowRDD = rdd1.map(x => x.split(" "))
    .map(attributes => 
      Row(attributes(0), attributes(1), attributes(2), attributes(3), attributes(4), attributes(5), attributes(6), attributes(7), attributes(8))
      )
   // rowRDD.foreach(println)

    def combiner(arr : Array[String])  = {

     val len = arr.length
     if (len <= 15)
     {

       var val0  = arr(0)
     var val1  = arr(1)
     var val2 = arr(2)
     var val3  = arr(3).concat(arr(4))
     var val4  = arr(5).concat(arr(6)).concat(arr(7))
     var val5  = arr(8)
     var val6 = arr(9)
       var last = arr.last
       var value : String = null


    for(i <- 10 until len-1) {
     if(value == null)
           value = arr(i)
      else           
      value = value.concat(arr(i))

    }

       Row(val0, val1, val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,value,last)
     }
     else 
     {

     var val0  = arr(0)
     var val1  = arr(1)
     var val2 = arr(2)
     var val3  = arr(3).concat(arr(4))
     var val4  = arr(5).concat(arr(6)).concat(arr(7))
     var val5  = arr(8)
     var val6 = arr(9)
     var val7  = arr(10).concat(arr(11)).concat(arr(12)).concat(arr(13))
     .concat(arr(14)).concat(arr(15)).concat(arr(16)).concat(arr(17)).concat(arr(17)).concat(arr(18)).concat(arr(19))
     var val8  = arr(20)
     var last = arr.last

    //val len1 = arr.length
    var value : String = null
    for(i <- 10 until len-1) {
     if(value == null)
           value = arr(i)
      else           
      value = value.concat(arr(i))

    }
  // Row(len,val0, val1, val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8)
 Row(val0, val1, val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,value,last)
     }
      }

     val rowRDD1 = rdd1.map(x => x.split(" "))
    .map{attributes => 
     combiner(attributes)
     }
      rowRDD1.foreach(println)

    val data = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD1, schema)
   data.show()
  }
}
```

and here is the screenshot of the o/p:
[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsfrB.jpg)